# Why type assertion of an interface equal to nil in type switch non-nil branch?

Tags: go, types

Given the codes

```golang
type Int struct {
    v int
}

func typeAssert(val any) {
    switch v := val.(type) {
    case nil:
        fmt.Println("val type is nil")
    case *Int:
        fmt.Println("val type is *Int")
        if v == nil {
            fmt.Println("val after type assertion is nil?")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var i1 *Int
    typeAssert(i1)
}
```

Output:

```
val type is *Int
val after type assertion is nil?
```

What confuses me is that since the `*Int` is matched in `switch v := val.(type)`, why could the `v == nil` be `true`? If the  `v == nil` be `true`, the `case nil` could be matched, actually, it does not.

Comment: Interface is a type and a value pair. The type is `*Int`, on which the type assert switch works and the value is `nil`

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are two kinds of `nil` with an interface value:

1. A `nil` interface, which would hit the first branch of your type switch. This is like `var x interface{} = nil` - not only is the value `nil`, the *type* is also `nil`.
2. A `nil` *value*, like `var x interface = (nil)(*Int)`. This hits the second branch, because it has a type, the type matches the type in the `switch`, but the value is `nil`. In the code, `v` is a `*Int` whose value is `nil`.